# What kind of animal is a Pangolin as in "Precise Pangolin"?

Tags: 12.04

i have a question.
Might not be ubuntu-related but it's worth trying.
For those who are wondering,yes,i have a ubuntu laptop.
So,this laptop is running 12.04,and i picked the "Precise Pangolin" background.
And may i ask:
What kind of animal is that?
I've been wondering what is that for a long time.

Comment: A Pangolin? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangolin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks kind of like an armadillo you can get more details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangolin